# Merging multiple CSV files into one using least amount of memory in Python

Tags: python, csv, zip

I am trying to merge more than 100 csv files which has millions of records. 
Each CSV has some columns which are common (but the column name case is different in some csvs Example, column1 or Column1) but some of them are totally different.
How can I combine these files with all the common columns merged as one column while others merged as different columns. 
I have tried other solutions available on the stackoverflow but it takes around 1 hour to load the data which I want to reduce.
I have to use least amount of memory.

```py
import csv
csv_files = os.listdir('path')
directory = 'path'
print(csv_files)
print(len(csv_files))
print(directory)

import csv
fieldNames = []
for filename in csv_files:
    filename = directory+filename
    print(filename)
    with open(filename, "r", newline="") as input_file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(input_file)
        headers = reader.fieldnames
        for h in headers:
            if h not in fieldNames:
                fieldNames.append(h)

print(fieldNames)

with open(directory+"merged_csv.csv","w", newline="") as output_file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, fieldnames=fieldNames, extrasaction='ignore', delimiter=';')
    for fileName in csv_files:
        fileName = directory+fileName
        with open(fileName,"r", newline="") as input_file:
            row_count = sum(1 for row in input_file)
            reader = csv.DictReader(input_file)
            for line in reader:
                writer.writerow(line)
```

Comment: The shown code looks like a good approach. What type of memory do you mean: RAM, harddrive or both?

Comment: @MichaelButscher it takes around 1 hour to read the data. Therefore I am trying to find if there is any other approach I can use to reduce it.

Comment: You can at least omit the calculation of "row_count" if you don't need the value.

Comment: @MichaelButscher oh yes